# how to replace word in python without use of any library or functions

Tags: python, replace

sentence :- this is cow
I want to replace this cow word with dog.

```
accepted_strings = {'DOG', 'Dog', 'dog'}

a= raw_input('Enter a word:')
for a in accepted_strings:
    while(a == 'dog')   
    print('this is cow')
do:
    print(a)
```

I tried this but not meet expected output.

Comment: You can use `str.replace` which is a method, not sure if you consider that as a function or not. Also this is not valid Python code

Comment: No i dont want to use .replace , .append or any methods

Comment: `'this is cow'.replace('cow', 'dog')`.

Comment: @HarnishShah: then there is nothing we can do to help you, sorry. `str.replace()` is a standard method, not a library. Applying arbitrary constraints like that leaves you with next to zero options. Without methods, you are left with iteration and slicing, and explaining how that's all going to work is too broad.

Comment: question is really poorly worded but here is how you can do it I have written soln to met bare minimum expectation ie soln can replace given word with replacement word it will work as long as len(sentence ) > replacement word obviously many improvements can be done [link](https://pastebin.com/B3DhRmrH)

Answer (score 2):

I don't see why you don't wanna use `.replace()` but here's an edit

```
s = "foo bar baz"
result = ""
for i in s.split():
     if i == "foo":
         i = "chocolate"
     result += i

print(result)  # "chocolate bar baz"
```

I however strongly recommend to use `str.replace()`, I mean it's in the standard library, if you don't want to use it then why using `for` or `list()` or even `print()`?

Comment: first one prints `foo bar baz`

Comment: Oo true, forgot to add `.split()` but I guess he does not want to use ̀.split()` too

Comment: This prints `chocolatebarbaz`; `str.split()` produces a list without the spaces you split on.

Comment: s = raw_input('Enter yr sentance:')
#s = "this is cow"
ans = ""
c = 0
for i in range(len(s)):
 if(s[i] == "c"):
  if(s[i+1] == "o"):
   if(s[i+2] == "w"):
    ans += "d"
    c += 1
 else:
  if(c != 0):
   if(c == 1):
    ans += "o"
    c = 2
   else:
    ans += "g"
    c = 0
  else:
   ans +=s[i]
print(ans)